# Why do parts of a namespace count as a namespace

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a namespace that looks like this:

```
namespace MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.HttpClient
```

Then I have a method declared in that file like this:

```
public static async Task<HttpClient> AddAuthentication(this HttpClient httpClient)
```

That gives an error that says:

> HttpClient is a namespace but is used like a type
>   Type name expected, but namespace found

Testing shows that **any** value that is dot separated in the namespace will conflict with the type.

**My question is, why does it do this?**

I want to understand what value .Net gets out of making each dot spaced part of the namespace be considered a namespace by itself.  Can just a part of a namespace be used somehow?

As a bonus side question, is there a well accepted workaround to this?  The ideas that come to mind are:

- *Underscore Spacing*: MyCompany_AspDotNet_Extensions_HttpClient
- *Lowercase Naming*: mycompany.aspdotnet.extensions.httpclient
- *Fully reference all conflicting types*: `Task<HttpClient>` to `Task<System.Net.Http.HttpClient>`
- *Don't use any types in my namespace names*: MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.WebCalls

I am not a fan of most of those.  But if I have to choose one, I will go with the last one.  But when I do that I find that I am trying to find another name for something that already has a good name.

Comment: By "in that file" do you mean "in that namespace"?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Testing shows that any value that is dot separated in the namespace will conflict with the type"* (specifically, what is a "value that is dot separated" and what "type" does it conflict with)?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is first looking at the current namespace for type resolution and has found a conflict, since the namespace has the same name as the type you're trying to extend.

One way to fix this is to specify the fully-qualified type name that we're referencing in the extension method since the name alone is colliding with the (more local) namespace:

```
namespace MyCompany.Extensions.HttpClient
{
    public static class HttpClientExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<System.Net.Http.HttpClient> AddAuthentication(
            this System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            // Extension method implementation here
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another way to resolve it is to put your `using` statement inside the namespace rather than outside, so the compiler finds it first:

```
namespace MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.HttpClient
{
    using System.Net.Http;

    public static class HttpClientExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<HttpClient> AddAuthentication(this HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            // Extension method implementation here
        }
    }
}
```

---

But a possibly better way to fix this is to just have a single namespace for *all* extension methods, and then create classes for each type, like `class HttpClientExtensions`. This will also remove the naming conflict, and reduces the overall number of namespaces needed (it's a little redundant to have such a specific namespace name for extension methods, since they need to live in a class anyway).

For example:

```
namespace MyCompany.ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class HttpClientExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<HttpClient> AddAuthentication(this HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            // Extension method implementation here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answer(s) here address how to fix this, I will address your confusion:

> ```
> namespace MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.HttpClient
> ```

You don't have one namespace named `MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.HttpClien`. What you have is a namespace `HttpClient` nested inside a namespace `Extensions` nested inside a namespace `AspDotNet` nested inside a namespace `MyCompany`. That's just how C# works (and most of the similar languages).

Answer (score 1):

C# compiler just works that way. When it finds an unknown identifier, it goes up the scope and tries to match it to something. In your case, this is a namespace. And since it expects a type, it will complain.

This will not happen if you fully-qualify HttpClient type or even if you include a `using` directive after the namespace (in this case, the compiler finds your type before the namespace becomes a problem).

```
namespace MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.HttpClient
{
  using System.Net.Http;

  // ...
  public static async Task<HttpClient> AddAuthentication(this HttpClient httpClient)
  // ...
}
```

Usually, you don't want to include a class name in its namespace (although, strictly speaking, you're not really doing it here). Instead, you may try grouping the classes by their purpose or technology or similar. In this regard, your last example (`MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.WebCalls`) is better than others on your list.

Some examples

```
MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.Web // every ASP.NET extension (?)
MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.Client // extensions for when we act as a client
MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.Communication // extensions for communicating between client and server
MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.Http // only http communication extensions
MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions.Http.Serialization // only for some special serialization over HTTP
MyCompany.AspDotNet.Extensions // or just put everything in one namespace (and group them later, when you realize you can't find anything anymore)
```